# How to delete WooCommerce Products than have a specific custom field?

Tags: custom-field, woocommerce-offtopic

I'm using a plugin that adds a wholesale price to WooCommerce products.

Now I need to delete all the products that have an empty wholesale price to only keep the products I want to keep on the wholesale part of my store.

Unfortunately, WP doesn't have the possibility to filter like I want to do to display only those kind of wholesale products and then bulk delete them.

The name of the field is `wholesale_customer_wholesale_prices`.

How can I achieve that easily?

Thanks a lot

Comment: By "field", do you mean that `wholesale_customer_wholesale_prices` is the name of the key of the postmeta entry?

Comment: @kero yes that's it.

Answer (score 0):

WooCommerce products is a custom post type called `product`. We can use that to start for querying posts. Now you say you want to find those posts, that either don't have a postmeta entry with the key `wholesale_customer_wholesale_prices` or ones that have an entry that has an empty value.

```
DELETE p
FROM wp_posts p
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta pm
ON
    (p.ID = pm.post_id
    AND
    pm.meta_key LIKE 'wholesale_customer_wholesale_prices')
WHERE
    p.post_type LIKE 'product'
    AND
        (
            pm.meta_value LIKE ''
            OR
            pm.meta_value IS NULL
        );
```

This query will delete all products that have the an `''` (empty string) or `NULL` as value for the relationship.

Now you're left with products that never had the relationship.

```
DELETE p
FROM wp_posts p
LEFT OUTER JOIN wp_postmeta pm
ON
    (p.ID = pm.post_id
    AND
    pm.meta_key LIKE 'wholesale_customer_wholesale_prices')
WHERE
    p.post_type LIKE 'product'
    AND
    pm.meta_key IS NULL;
```

---

Of course, with direct db manipulation like this, you should first test this in a test environment and not directly on the live site. This will only delete the entries in `wp_posts` table, there are many plugins/queries available for cleaning up the db after that (e.g. removing orphaned postmeta entries)